# Keeping track of node_modules with npm shinkwrap and git

Tags: node.js, git, npm, npm-shrinkwrap

I'm on a node project with a launcher and several homemade plugins. Those plugins are marked as dependencies in the launcher `package.json` with the git repo adress.

I recently tried `npm shrinkwrap` which perfectly give me the commit used for each of my plugins but any dev on plugins will break this. I trid to use `npm link` for my git repo, but they aren't tracked by `shrinkwrap` anymore.

So basically, how can I have cloned repo for my plugins where I can work **and** a way to get a snapshot of my dependencies at a precise moment?

Thank you for any lead you could give me.

Comment: Maybe i'm miss-understanding the problem. The issue is, When using shrinkwrap, you're not getting any updates made to the github repos, right? You'll have the same problem with any other modules you have installed while using a shrinkwrap.

Comment: If the problem is instead that updating your plugin repos are updating where you are including them with shrinkwrap when you don't want it to, you should probably be using tags so that you can specify precisely which tag you want from the repo.

Comment: Actually I would like shrinkwrap to refer to the commit sha of my repo (doesn't need to bump version & tag). The problem is my git repo needs to be in node_modules to get shrinked but it will break `npm install` if it find git repos

Comment: Your adding your git repo as a dependency right?

Comment: They are in my package.json with the git URL but for now I need to override the node_modules/my_plugin content with a git clone so I could push my newly coded content. I'm aware this is not ideal, so any thoughts are welcome ;)